# Weekly Email from content query web part

Tags: email, content-query-web-part

We have several announcement lists we want to consolidate into a single weekly email - we do not want X separate emails being sent to each user.

We can roll them up into a content query webpart but this has RSS only and I doubt my users will review this.

Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem?